# How to remove ftp network?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, ftp

I have a dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04.
Since the begining I had Windows Network , but few days ago a new network called MACHINE appeared (machine is the name of my laptop). I dont know why. I had given my laptop to my cousin for a day , so i thought that maybe he knew but he also has no idea.(See the attatched image) Any advice on how to remove this network.

[image]

Also on running "nmap 192.168.1.1" , I get following result[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably your router, based on it's IP. Many residential routers support ftp and telnet. The reverse name `_gateway` supports this

Thus, you will have to check the manual of the router for how to disable said services on the router. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

You can verify this by running the command `ip route` and verify that it has a line saying

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ...
```